# Apparent Ubuntu 18.04 Intel RAID 0 Hardware Incompatibility

Tags: boot, partitioning, system-installation, raid

I have created an Intel RST hardware RAID-0 array from 2 500 MB HDDs. Ubuntu 18.04 detects this to my pleasure. However when I get to the "[!!] Partition disks" menu it either is too advanced for me understand, even with the manual, or there is some sort of idiosyncratic critical problem I am having.

I only have the options to "Configure iSCSI volumes," "Undo changes to partitions" (This option results in an unrecoverable error), and "Finish Partitioning and write changes to disk." The first option I am completely lost on and the last option gives the error "No root file system is defined. / Please correct this from the partitioning menu." My attempts to configure iSCSI has always ended in this error: "No iSCSI targets were discovered on [Attempted ID]" 
See attached photos --> [Limited Partition Options.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mBZzS.jpg)    [Cannot install root file.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0h52A.jpg)    [Cannot figure out iSCSI.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bavSL.jpg)

Thanks in advance,
Austin

Comment: Please log in to edit your post. The change looks too drastic to approve unless it's definitely yours!

Comment: Thank you Zanna, but it was me. I've never had such a problem installing any linux distro on Intel Raid 0. I do not know why the setup changed, then it changed back to original problem. I figured out iSCSI and that has nothing to do with the RAID 0 already setup preboot. I finally gave up and deleted the Intel Raid array and just installed a software raid. Things are working good enough.

Answer (score 0):

I used a drive to install 18.04 first. Then add the array into the system with Intel RST. The first drive sda has the U18.04. Then sdb, sdc, sdd is my RAID0 array.

```
$lsblk
NAME                        MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE  MOUNTPOINT
sda                           8:0    0 149.1G  0 disk
└─sda1                        8:1    0 149.1G  0 part
  ├─action--1004--vg-root   253:0    0 148.1G  0 lvm   /
  └─action--1004--vg-swap_1 253:1    0   976M  0 lvm   [SWAP]
sdb                           8:16   0 931.5G  0 disk
└─md126                       9:126  0   2.6T  0 raid0
sdc                           8:32   0 931.5G  0 disk
└─md126                       9:126  0   2.6T  0 raid0
sdd                           8:48   0 931.5G  0 disk
└─md126                       9:126  0   2.6T  0 raid0
```